# A property of a linear image of the cube

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, polyhedra

Let $[0,1]^3$ denote the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Let $L : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a surjective linear map,
and let $H := L([0,1]^3)$ (which is generically a hexagon).

Can you provide a proof of this statement ?

If $w_1$, $w_2$, and $w_1 + w_2$ are all in $H$,
then there exist $v_1$, $v_2 \in [0,1]^3$ so that:

1. $L(v_1)=w_1$ and  $L(v_2)=w_2$
2. $v_1 + v_2 \in [0,1]^3$

---

Property 2. is the hard part.

Comment: Given the loss of dimension, does this give us that $\exists z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ so that $L(z) = (0,0)$?  If so, we can start with $v_1$ and $v_2$, and try to find $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $v_1+c_1\cdot z$, $v_2+c_2\cdot z$, and $v_1+v_2+(c_1+c_2)\cdot z$ are all in $[0,1]^3$.

Comment: Yes.  The dimension of the null-space must be 1, so the null-space is a line.  This means that $v_1$ must be in the intersection of a translate of this line and the cube.  This is a line segment - possibly a single point.    Assume now that $H$ is a hexagon.   If $w_1$ is in the boundary of $H$, then this intersection is a point, i.e. $v_1$ is unique.  And similarly for $w_2$ and $w_1+w_2$.  This might be useful in finding a counter-example, but I couldn't find one.  If $w_1$ is in the interior of $H$, then the intersection is a non-trivial line segment.

Comment: It suffices to consider the case where $L$ is an orthogonal projection onto some subspace.  This makes the statement a bit more visually appealing and intuitively true, but I still don't have an idea for a proof.

Comment: Correction: The dimension of the null-space must be at least 1.  It is possible (but less interesting) that L(x,y,z) = (0,0)

Comment: I think we start with $v_1$ (and $v_2$), and find a $c_1$ such that $v_1^\prime = v_1 + {c_1}{z}$ has at least one zero coordinate and is otherwise in the cube.  I'm not sure where to go next, but I think that $v_1^\prime$ and $v_2^\prime$ can be your final result.   (May not work.  The only required intersection between ${c}{z}$ and the cube is the origin...)

Comment: 4 days ago I asked a generalization of this question at:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503594/a-lifting-property-for-linear-maps-on-cubes.   Because sometimes a generalization can spark some insight into the specialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is NO, and here is a counterexample.

Let $L(x,y,z)=(x-z,y-z)$, $w_1=(1,1)$, $w_2=(-\frac{1}{2},0)$, $v_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $v_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$.

Clearly $L(v_1)=w_1$ iff $v_1$ is of the form $v_1=F_1(z_1)=(1+z_1,1+z_1,z_1)$, and this $F_1(z_1)$ is in $[0,1]^3$ iff $z_1=0$. In particular, $w_1\in H$.

Clearly $L(v_2)=w_2$ iff $v_2$ is of the form $v_2=F_2(z_2)=(z_2-\frac{1}{2},z_2,z_2)$, and this $F_2(z_2)$ is in $[0,1]^3$ iff $z_2\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$. In particular, $w_2\in H$.

Moreover, the vector $F_3(z_1,z_2)=F_1(z_1)+F_2(z_2)=(\frac{1}{2}+(z_1+z_2),1+z_1+z_2,z_1+z_2)$ is in $[0,1]^3$ iff $z_1+z_2=0$. In particular, $w_1+w_2\in H$ (take $z_1=z_2=0$).

Finally, if we want all three of $F_1,F_2,F_3$ to live in $H$, we get the impossible system $z_1=0,z_2\in[\frac{1}{2},1],z_1+z_2=0$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: This checks out; great !  In this counterexample $H$ is the hexagon with vertices (1,0), (1,1), (0,1), (-1,0), (-1,-1), and (0,-1).  The points $w_1$ and $w_1+w_2$ are in $\partial H$, and this forces $v_1 = (1,1,0)$ and $v_1+v_2=(\frac{1}{2},1,0)$.  Thus $v_2=(-\frac{1}{2},0,0)$ which is NOT in $[0,1]^3$.  This counterexample also gives a negative answer to my more general question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503594/a-lifting-property-for-linear-maps-on-cubes, but @Ewan deserves credit for answering that one and not me.

Answer (score 0):

## Incorrect answer, affine but not linear

I think I can provide a counter example.

Suppose the mapping is such that $(x,y,1)$ maps to $(x,y)$, and $(x,y,0)$ maps to $(x-1000,y-1000)$.  Then $w_1 = (0.1,0.2)$, $w_2 = (0.2,0.1)$ and $w_1+w_2 = (0.3,0.3)$.

This gives us $v_1 = (0.1+n_1, 0.2+n_1, 1-{n_1\over1000})$ and $v_2 = (0.2+n_2, 0.1+n_2, 1- {n_2\over1000})$
where $n_1,n_2 \in [0,0.8]$

This places the third coordinate of $v_1+v_2$ at $\ge 1.9994$, which is outside the cube.

Comment: If $L$ is linear, it maps (0,0,0) to (0,0).  But your map takes (0,0,0) to (-1000,-1000).  It is affine, but not linear.