# A "lifting property" for linear maps on cubes?

Tags: linear-programming, polytopes

Let $L : \mathbb{R}^n \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear map that is surjective.
Let $[0,1]^n$ denote the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$, 
and let $Z := L([0,1]^n) \hspace{5pt}$  ($Z$ is a *zonotope*).
Let $T : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be linear with $T([0,1]^N) \subset Z$.

Is there a linear map $T' : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^n$ so that
$$
L \circ T' = T  \hspace{30pt} \text{and} \hspace{30pt} T'([0,1]^N) \subset [0,1]^n  \text{ ?}
$$

Or in "categorical" terms, is there a linear $T'$ that makes this diagram commute ?

[image]

So $T'$ might be called a "lift" of $T$ restricted to the appropriate cube
(the 3 maps on the edges of the triangle are restrictions of linear maps to cubes, but the restriction notation is suppressed).

**Remark 1.**
If $T'$ exists, then $T([0,1]^N) \subset Z$ (trivially).
So the question asks about the converse of this.

**Remark 2.**
$T([0,1]^N)$ is a *subzonotope* of $Z$.
And $T'([0,1]^N)$ is a zonotope that "covers" $T([0,1]^N)$.

**Remark 3.**
If $[0,1]^n$ is replaced by the Euclidean unit ball $B^n$  (and similarly for $[0,1]^N$)
then the answer is *yes*.
We can let $T' := L^+ \circ T$, where $L^+$ is the pseudo-inverse of $L$.

**Remark 4.**
If $m=n$, this is trivial.
$L$ is invertible.
Take $T' := L^{-1} \circ T$.

**Remark 5.**
If  $N=1$, this is trivial.
Pick any $v \in [0,1]^n$ so $L(v) = T(1)$.
Then define $T'(1) = v$.

**Remark 6.**
If $m=1$, this is relatively easy.
Let $e_i$ denote the $i$'th elementary basis vector.
If all $L(e_i) > 0, ~ i=1,\ldots,n$,
then we can define $T'(e_j) :=  T(e_j)  [ L(\sum e_i) ]^{-1}  \sum e_i$.
In the general case then a similar formula works, depending on the sign of $T(e_j)$.

**Remark 7.**
The simplest non-straightforward case is $n=3$, $m=2$, and $N=2$.
I think the answer is yes, but cannot prove it or find a counterexample.
A few days ago I submitted this case as separate question:
[A property of a linear image of the cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3495344/171444)

Thank you.

Comment: Ewan Delanoy has given a counterexample in the special case $n=3$, $m=2$, and $N=2$.  So the answer is NO.  See the special case in this earlier question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495344/a-property-of-a-linear-image-of-the-cube